# NRF24 CE and CSN connections without I/O pins easily accessible

Tags: nrf24l01+

I want 2 Arduinos communicating to each other, but only in one direction.  Arduino A = tx  and Arduino B = rx.

I have this working fine connecting CE and CSN on each NRF24 to pins 4 and 5 on each Arduino and using the nRF24L01 library.  No problem.

Since Arduino A will always ONLY be transmitting and Arduino B will always ONLY be receiving, can I do this with CE and CSN instead:

Arduino A --- put CSN to GND  and put CE to 3.3V
Arduino B --- put CSN to 3.3V and put CE to 3.3V

As to why?  This would simply help me interface the NFR24 to existing custom PCB's I've made which have no ***easy*** access to I/O pins.  My PCB's do have easy access to MISO, MOSI, and SCK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you really do need the CE pin for both TX and RX modes.  See the following excerpts from the nRF24L01 datasheet.  They work practically the same for nRF24L01+:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems the CE pin is only used for TX, or to put it into standby. I think you can just connect it to VCC.

The CSN is required for SPI.

PS this [RF24 library](https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/blob/master/RF24.cpp#L18) supports using the same pin for both CE and CSN. You'd have to define `RF24_TINY` for this to work.